# how can tell element to get specified styles?

Tags: html, wordpress, css

i developing a WordPress plugin and my plugin working fine on a sample template. but when i install it on other templates, it gets style attributes from other sources.

for example in template css files the author writes:

```
li{font-size: 20px;}
```

and etc.

how i can tel my elements to get css attributes just from my css files?

Comment: Your plugin should probably have very few style rules. For example if you force your plugin to be black, it wouldn't work on a white theme. Of course it depends on the nature of your plugin what's desired. For important parts you could decide to give your plugins` root tag a single unique class name like `awesome-plugin-name` and prefix all your style rules with `.awesome-plugin-name`. Never ever use `!important`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't work like that. You have to override the css in another sheet. (Or somewhere in the same sheet).

Like this:

```css
li{font-size: 20px;}

.small-list > li{font-size: 10px;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List item 1.1</li>  
  <li>List item 1.2</li>
  <li>List item 1.3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="small-list">
  <li>List item 2.1</li>  
  <li>List item 2.2</li>
  <li>List item 2.3</li>
</ul>
```

You don't have to use `!important` because if you use a parent, it's already more specific than the `li` in general.

Another option is to place your stylesheet after the one from the template.

```
<link href="template-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="plugin-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If you use the exact same css selectors, the 2nd sheet will override the first.

Another good reason for not using `!important` is because you don't want to override all rules. You'r between the template and the author of the page. Most likely the author is using a WYSIWYG editor. If you use `!important`, it may happen that you override the rules which the author really wants.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the CSS style of the template. You can do this by:

1. Using the `!important CSS` declaration
   Example: `li{padding: 10px !important}`
2. Add a parent div before the class/element. Example:

From

```
li{padding: 10px}
```

change it to
`body li {padding: 10px}`

That should work. Cheers!